# How to send listview item image from one activity to another using xml parser

Tags: android, android-intent

I have made an app in which I am retrieving data from `weburl` using `xmlparsing` in a `listview` (with image and few text fields) and I wrote code for `onItemClick` and values displays to another activity, but I am not able to send image from one activity to another, but sending text data by using `listview` item.

Can someone guide me and write some code, with little bit of description also?

Here is some of my code:

MainActivity Code:

```
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
         // getting values from selected ListItem
            String title = ((TextView)  view.findViewById
             (R.id.title)).getText().toString();
            String artist = ((TextView) view.findViewById
               (R.id.artist)).getText().toString();
            String duration = ((TextView) view.findViewById
              (R.id.duration)).getText().toString();
            String image=((ImageView)view.findViewById
             (R.id.list_image)).getImageMatrix().toString();
            //byte[] array=null;
            //Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray
                     //  (array, 0, array.length);


            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent
                     (getApplicationContext(),        SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, title);
            in.putExtra(KEY_ARTIST, artist);
            in.putExtra(KEY_DURATION, duration);
            in.putExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL, image);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });     
 }  
     }

    SingleMenuItemActivity Code:-

    public class SingleMenuItemActivity  extends Activity {

// XML node keys
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
private static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
private static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
private static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single_list_item);

    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get XML values from previous intent

    String title = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
    String artist = in.getStringExtra(KEY_ARTIST);
    String duration = in.getStringExtra(KEY_DURATION);
    String image = in.getStringExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL);

    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
    TextView lblCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email_label);
    TextView lblDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_label);
    ImageView lblImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_label);   


    lblName.setText(title);
    lblCost.setText(artist);
    lblDesc.setText(duration);
        //Getting error in below line
        //the method setImageResource(int) is the type 
        //Image View is not applicable for the argument(string)
    lblImage.setImageResource(image);//(R.drawable.rihanna);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert this image to bitmap and pass it as bundle using Intent.putExtra() to the next activity.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass the image through `Bundle`, instead pass the `image path as String data`, and in each activity, wherever you require image, create image from that image path.

Answer (score 0):

```
 in.putExtra(KEY_IMAGE, image);
```

where image is byte[] ..Any image can be converted to a bytearray..
and while retieving

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(array, 0, array.length);
```

`

Comment: Hi Sheetal, as you told me i did the same, i am getting image but which i have defined in drawable, not from listview and i want whenever user will click on listview item then image of selected row will be shown, but getting error message:- the method setImageResource(int) is the type Image View is not applicable for the argument(string).

Comment: why are you taking string than even u dont have to take integer sice integer is only for drawable since they have  a ID..whatever listview you are selecting you are getting the image which you can get as Drawable if u have setBackground in xml..And Drawable can be easily converted to ByteArray..Check if Matrix can??